# Tomcat Throws Back 400 When I Post a JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, tomcat, gson, http-status-code-400

I am posting the following JSON to Tomcat server but Tomcat server returns 400 without even calling the servlet -

```
[
    {
        "q": {
            "field": "uri",
            "value": "c:Data#part3"
        },
        "uri_pre_select": true
    }
]
```

Inside the servlet the following code is deserializing the JSON -

```
//  JSONObject reqJSONObj;
MyRequest[] data = gson.fromJson(reqJSONObj.toString(), MyRequest[].class);
```

When I remove the enclosing square brackets [  ] in the request JSON, then my servlet is called normally. This means there is something in the JSON, that is making it unacceptable to Tomcat.

But I don't have any clue why can't I post an array. Can anyone see a problem in the JSON that I am posting here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake -

The handler method was accepting a JSONObject. When I changed the type to JSONArray it was getting called by Tomcat.